# Did the BIOS do that?

Tags: updates, hp, bios

I have an old HP dc5000 SFF and I updated the BIOS from 1.00 to 1.43. Before that update, I install Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal and flickering and tearing occurs everywhere. So I reinstalled Windows and flashed the BIOS and installed Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. The flickering was gone for some weird reason... Before that, I upgraded from an Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat to Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal and the flickering was also gone. Did that BIOS update fix all this?

My specs are:

HP dc5000 Business Small Form Factor,
Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot 32-Bit,
Intel Pentium 4 2.40 GHz,
Intel 86865g Integrated Graphics,
0.99 GB RAM

Just tell what happened. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu at all. Not even to a linux distro. This is more related to hardware/firmware stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, looks more like an Intel drivers thing. 11.04 needed a PPA to have good drivers working, 11.10 already has those drivers without need to get them from a PPA. Probably that PPA was used when you upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04 before and the packages were updated.

It was very likely a driver thing and not the BIOS update.